# Drag, drop and fix a node in D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a HTML File to display graphs using D3JS. The JSFiddle is in [this link here](https://jsfiddle.net/vgy1s8k3/). I know that I must use the function to enable the fixing of node position on dragging and dropping:

```
var drag = force.drag()
.on("dragstart", dragstart);

function dragstart(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}
```

However, on dragging and dropping a node, I am unable to fix the position. I want the same functionality as shown in [this link](http://bl.ocks.org/norrs/2883411) .I don't want the node to revert to its original position. How do I change it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to set a 'fixed' node property to true on dragstart, this will allow to append the position.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>

var width = 1280,
      height = 960;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll("graph.link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll("graph.node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.fill); })
      .call(force.drag);

  var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);

    function dragstart(d) {
      d.fixed = true;
    }

  node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name });

    force.on("tick", tick);

    function tick() {
      link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

      node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    };


});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have Updated the js fiddle , kindly check since you have edited the question see https://jsfiddle.net/vgy1s8k3/1/

Answer (score 0):

From this example : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558

You need to add a call to drag function :

```
var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);
```

Which is the following :

```
function dragstart(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}
```

The key point is setting `d.fixed` to `true`.

EDIT

In your fiddle you weren't calling node_drag. So you need to call that on the nodes like so  :

```
 var node = gnodes.append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { 
        thelistofcolors[d.group] = color(d.group);
        return color(d.group); })
      .call(node_drag); // <<<<<<<this line
```

And then change the tick to a function so you can call it later :

```
  force.on("tick", tick);

  function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    gnodes.attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')'; 
    });



  };
```

Updated fiddle with all data showing (not filtered on click) : https://jsfiddle.net/vgy1s8k3/4/

Comment: This was found really easy, next time I recommend a bit of research prior to asking a question

Comment: Ive actually tried to put it.. I dont know what the error is.. check this gist - https://gist.github.com/pnpninja/4779e8242ec7b971cf36142c89055cbf

Comment: @PrateekNarendra wheres your data ? Also, why are you calling force.drag and not node_drag ? Just seen the fiddle, give me a minute

Comment: You werent calling node_drag and you didnt have a tick function. Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vgy1s8k3/2/, I know you are filtering the nodes so some disapear, but here's the working fiddle with all the data showing : https://jsfiddle.net/vgy1s8k3/3/